# High power version of Colpitts or Hartley oscillator

Tags: power-supply, power, switch-mode-power-supply, oscillator

As I understand these circuits are intended for low efficiency, low power. If one would want higher power and efficiency, but also simplicity, what circuits should be considered?

LLC resonant power converter probably be the one, but it is rather complex. Is there something between (Hartley, Colpitts) and LLC power converter in terms of complexity and efficiency?

If I understand correctly Colpitts and Hartley oscillators are limited to be below 50% efficiency, due to using resistor as a load. And circuits like LLC are closer to 90% efficiency. Something of 70% efficiency would be of interest, assuming lower efficiency grants simpler circuit than LLC.

Goal is to make about 1 MHz, 1 W, sine wave output, with efficiency of 70%. Output at other frequencies to be considered as waste. The lossy tank circuit is the load. If energy is provided to a tank circuit, and then tank circuit dissipates it over time, I would consider it to be a useful work.

Keep in mind the transistor switching losses. If transistor is ON only 1% of the time, or switches much more often, it will increases losses for the same power. It is an acceptable solution, but if there is an answer that accounts for it, it would be preferred.

If there is no solution, I will accept it as an answer too, if there would be an explanation why is it so. For example that Colpitts uses resistor for second path to switch, and LLC uses another transistor, and other options are not as good as these two.

Answer through amplifier classes would be good too. That would explain why particular circuit has particular efficiency through associating these circuits with an according amplifier class for better understanding.

Comment: You are coming at this all wrong. Define what you want (properly) and forget about Colpitts or Hartley or anything else and see what happens. You are loading your question with so much clutter as to make it difficult to answer. How can you define efficiency of your output when you don't specify a load impedance. Rethink please. 1 watt is not high power BTW.

Comment: Do you want to generate 1W at 1MHz or do you want an oscillator to do the same? Normally you’d have an oscillator drive an amplifier. Depending on the amount of distortion you could tolerate, the simplest would be a square wave oscillator driving a mosfet in class C configuration with a tuned circuit. Efficiency would be high as the mosfet is purely switching.

Comment: Higher power comes with poorer thermal stability; higher efficiency (e.g. via class C) comes with poorer linearity, both will make a lousy oscillator. Make a good oscillator and drive an amplifier with it.

Comment: @Kartman class C comes with low duty cycle. I want to keep the 50% duty cycle.

Comment: @Andyaka load is a tank circuit, its oscillations. Square signal could in theory drive it efficiently, but with some problems, as in c class amplifier it is duty cycle that is bad. Thats why i mentioned colpits - to show what i want in the end. oscillating tank circuit, 50% duty cycle. Efficiency to be considered from battery to oscillations in a tank circuit

Comment: @user_1818839 sure, that will do. But what amplifier can have above 50% efficiency, 50% duty cycle?

Comment: @SurprisedSeagull That's a completely different question (and shows no research effort. What is the maximum efficiency of a Class B?)

Comment: A tank circuit doesn't theoretically use any power and, trying to imply a tank circuit as the  load by talking about a Colpitts oscillator is very obscure. I've designed very high quality linear sinewave tank circuits that were 14 V RMS and 10 A RMS (140 VA) fed from a DC supply that consumed only 6 watts. Don't load your question with assumptions about what is possible; you'll be surprised what you can achieve.

Comment: @user_1818839 answer through amplifier classes will work. Like colpitts is close to class A (is it? Im not sure), and LLC is close to class D (again, not sure). This would explain everything. I understand that those are different concepts, im just trying to show 'circuit like...', to make abstract concepts such as amplifier class be closer to particular circuits

Comment: @Andyaka its a good tank circuit, quality factor of about 20 I assume? Anyway, tank circuits do have some losses, this loss can be considered resistive. But there is a difference between smps working on resistive load directly, and working on a tank circuit, that works on resistive load. I wanted to make this distinction clear. Tank circuit + resistive loss is what im interested in

Comment: A sine wave has no duty cycle. If it were non continuous, then it wouldn’t be a sine wave. I’m puzzled your use of the term ‘duty cycle’

Comment: @Kartman sine is produced by the tank circuit. If quality factor is high, it will convert even square wave into a sine. By duty cycle I mean the transistor condition. If transistor is ON only for 1% of the time, it has its own problems. So, if a transistor is on 50% of the time, and tank circuits produces sine all the time, this is what I would want to see. This is how approximately colpitts and LLC resonant converters work.

Comment: If the circuit is generating your 1W at 1MHz sine wave, why is the duty cycle important? Your requirements have been satisfied. You need to add more context to the question.

Comment: @Kartman if transistor is ON only 1% of the time, then frequency will need to be reduced, to make switching losses comparable. And it would require many or bihger transistor, to survive peak current. But yeah, it is okay-ish solution.